# BLOB vs LongBLOB performance

Tags: mysql, hibernate, blob

What's the difference in performance between a mysql `BLOB` and a `LongBLOB`?

Are there some gotchas to watch out for?

Comment: Your queries are answered [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8946224/whats-the-exact-difference-between-choosing-tinyblob-and-longblob) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8931696/blob-and-storage-requirement)