# Can MySQL check that file exists?

Tags: mysql, file-exists

I have a table that holds relative paths to real files on HDD. for example:

```
SELECT * FROM images -->
id | path
1  | /files/1.jpg
2  | /files/2.jpg
```

Can I create a query to select all records pointing to non-existent files? I need to check it by MySql server exactly, without using an iteration in PHP-client.

Comment: This is a very bad design.

Comment: I don't believe that MySQL has any sort of access to the file system for this sort of thing. You will need to use an external language to achieve this.

Comment: Bogdan Burim, why bad? It's better to put image data in BINARY field or what?

Comment: See if http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8931696/blob-and-storage-requirement can be a suggestion for what you try to achieve

Answer (score 11):

I would go with a query like this:

```
SELECT id, path, ISNULL(LOAD_FILE(path)) as not_exists
FROM images
HAVING not_exists = 1
```

The function `LOAD_FILE` tries to load the file as a string, and returns `NULL` when it fails.

Please notice that a failure in this case might be due to the fact that mysql simply cannot read that specific location, even if the file actually exists.

EDIT:

As @ostrokach pointed out in comments, this isn't standard SQL, even though MySQL allows it, to follow the standard it could be:

```
SELECT *
FROM images
WHERE LOAD_FILE(PATH) IS NULL
```

Comment: I can't get this to work for myself. All files returned do in fact exist. What could mean this local location is unreadable to MySQL? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27495830/retrieve-a-list-of-missing-files-from-field-using-mysql?noredirect=1#comment43423726_27495830

Comment: It could be that the user running MySQL daemon cannot access the folder(s) which contain those file(s).

Comment: The `HAVING not_exists = 1` part is wrong, since you are not grouping by not_exists. I you want to select only those rows for which a file exists, you should do something like: `SELECT id, path FROM images WHERE LOAD_FILE(path) is NULL`;

Comment: Yes, it is not standard SQL but MySQL allows it. But I like your suggestion and I'll edit my answer :)

Comment: This seems wasteful. The LOAD_FILE function will read the contents of every file that does exist. That makes this query use a lot of I/O for nothing. Just because someone *can* do something doesn't mean it's a good idea. This task would be far better to write as a script!

Answer (score 5):

The MySQL `LOAD_FILE` command has very stringent requirements on the files that it can open. From the MySQL docs:

> [`LOAD_FILE`] Reads the file and returns the file contents as a string. To use this function, the file must be located on the server host, you must specify the full path name to the file, and you must have the FILE privilege. The file must be readable by all and its size less than max_allowed_packet bytes. If the secure_file_priv system variable is set to a non-empty directory name, the file to be loaded must be located in that directory.

So if the file can't be reached by the `mysql` user or any of the other requirements are not satisfied, `LOAD_FILE` will return `Null`.

---

You can get a list of IDs that correspond to missing files using `awk`:

```
mysql db_name --batch -s -e "SELECT id, path FROM images" \
    | awk '{if(system("[ -e " $2 " ]") == 1) {print $1}}' \
    >> missing_ids.txt
```

or simply using `bash`:

```
mysql db_name --batch -s -e "SELECT id, path FROM images" \
    | while read id path ; if [[ -e "$path" ]] ; then echo $id ; done
    >> missing_ids.txt
```

This also has the advantage of being much faster than `LOAD_FILE`.

Comment: If the file name contains a round bracket " ( ) " then this command throws errors. Is there a way around this so it can handle any kind of filename?

Comment: @CarstenSchmitz I added an example of using the bash while loop. You could try using that instead.

Answer (score 2):

MYSQL only handles the Database so there is no way for you to fire an SQL Statement to check on the HDD if the file exists. You need to iterate over the rows and check it with PHP.

Comment: thank you. I thought may be if mysql has fetures like LOAD DATA INFILE etc. in other words can access user files, then it can have something to check if file exists.

Comment: Or you can store your files in your database as Binary Large Object BLOB and check if they exists into the database

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible using stock MySQL. However you can write [UDF](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/adding-functions.html) (user-defined function), probably in C, load it using [CREATE FUNCTION](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-function.html) statement and use it from MySQL as you would use any built-in function.

Comment: For what I know, mysql custom created functions use only SQL.

Comment: @MatteoTassinari Please read linked resources. You can create "stored functions" that are written in SQL and you can create "user-defined functions" which are compiled into a shared library and loaded at runtime.

Comment: It seems I was wrong then, sorry, and thanks for pointing it out :)