# How to skip a row with file exists condition in laravel

Tags: laravel, search, eloquent

This is for a search query based on many input fields, i'm doing if statements inside the query based on the inputs, for example :

```
$query = Model::all();

if($field = Input::get('field'))
        $query->where('column_name', $field);
```

but what i want to do also is a condition to skip a row if there is no image with a name of that row id, like so :

```
if( file_exists('/img/'.$this_query->id) )
        $query->skip();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Option 1: would be to make an array of the filenames, then utilize the [`whereIn`](http://laravel.com/docs/master/queries#where-clauses) query builder method, which checks for the occurrence of a column value in an array.

```
$query = Model::query();

$filenames = scandir('/img');

// the following excludes any id's not in the $filenames array
$query = $query->whereIn('id', $filenames);
```

Option 2: Run the query and then [`filter`](http://laravel.com/api/5.0/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Collection.html#method_filter) the resulting Collection in Laravel.

```
$query = Model::query();
// ... then build up your query

// the following gets the query results and then filters them out
$collection = $query->get()->filter( function($item) {
    return file_exists('/img/'.$item->id);
}
```

*Rationale*: the database cannot check the filesystem during it's processing; so you either need to (Option 1) provide it a list from which to check, or (Option 2) do the checking *after* you [`get()`](http://laravel.com/api/5.0/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Builder.html#method_get) the results back from the query.

Comment: it's working for the moment, thank you :) , now i don't know if this scandir() function will use a lot of ressources and slow the website once it has traffic

Comment: one more question, is there a way to check if a file exists without grabbing all the files names ? just the one with the specific id ?

for example : $filenames = scandir('/img/'.$id);

Comment: I'm not really familiar with the performance of scandir(), but I would guess that it's probably n(number_of_files), i.e. dependent more on the number of files to scan, which might get bad if you have hundreds of files. Do you know the id's you need to check before doing the query? Are you only querying for one id at a time? Or is it a group of id's to check for? I'll update the answer with some alternate solutions.

Comment: you opened my eyes abt the fact that mysql can not check filesystem while reading tables, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17192827/can-mysql-check-that-file-exists , and i need to check while querying not after so i will do it with a cached array containing folders names, and then editing that table every CRUD on that folder, its beter for performence with lot of requests and files i guess ?